# alternative to DOM element 'new Image()' of browser implementation in headless-gl javascript?

Tags: node.js, image, browser, webgl

Currently I am using a webGL based browser implementation code at client end. It is working perfectly. But, I want to use the same code at server end. Yes, this is not browser based, pure javascript code using headless-gl wrapper.

While doing this I am facing a problem.

new `Image()` is identified by browser, but at server side I am getting error `Image is not defined`.

In node-webGL it can be used as

`*var Image = require("node-webgl").Image;*`,

but in headless-gl I tried with

`*require("gl").Image;`* and `*require('gl')(width, height, { preserveDrawingBuffer: true }).Image*`.

With the above I haven't had any success. Can someone offer some explanation, or advice on a proper place to look for a headless-gl manual?

Comment: The readme can https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl#how-are-image-and-video-elements-implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headless-gl only provides WebGL. It does not provide image loading which is not part of WebGL per se, images are part of HTML5

You could try the [images package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/images)

To load and get the data something like this should work

```
var images = require('images');
var img = images('/path/to/img.jpg');
var raw = img.toBuffer(images.TYPE_RAW);
var pixels = new Uint8Array(raw.buffer, 12); // skip the raw header
```

You could now upload the image

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, img.width(), img.height(),
              0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Or make a wrapper to emulate the WebGL API for images

```
gl.texImage2D = function(origFn) {
  return function(bind, mip, internalFormat) {
     var width;
     var height;
     var border;
     var format;
     var type;
     var data;
     if (arguments.length === 9) {
       // sig1: bind, mip, internalFormat, width, height, border, format, type, data
       width = arguments[3];
       height = arguments[4];
       border = arguments[5];
       format = arguments[6];
       type = arguments[7];
       data = arguments[8];
     } else if (arguments.length === 6) {
       // sig2: bind, mip, internalFormat, format, type, image
       format = arguments[3];
       type = arguments[4];
       img = arguments[6];
       var raw = img.toBuffer(images.TYPE_RAW);
       data = new Uint8Array(raw.buffer, 12); // skip the raw header           
       width = img.width();
       height = img.height();
       border = 0;
     } else {
       throw "Bad args to texImage2D";
     }
     gl.texImage2D(bind, mip, internalFormat, width, height, 
                   border, format, type, data);
  };
}(gl.texImage2D);
```

Comment: YesI tried. First passed as 6 parameters, but I got error. And then I tried as 9 parameters. This worked. But, after changes getting error at     _undefined:282
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, cube.VertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
                                                                                     ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'vertexPositionAttribute' of null
    at drawCube (eval at <anonymous>..._

Comment: `Cannot read property 'vertexPositionAttribute' of null at drawCube` means the object that you thought contained `vertexPositionAttribute` is null. That object `gl.shaderProgram`. `gl.shaderProgram` is something you made up. It's not part of WebGL. That's your own code.

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Sorry for that. Shaders are not getting loaded. 404 request. I am looking into it. :)